# Is there a better update system coming for Xcode?

Tags: xcode, software-update

Xcode 4.0.1 was released a few days ago, which means that I am once again downloading the 4.5 GB beast to update. Does anyone know if Apple plans to introduce a better update system?

Comment: Come on, people, how is this off topic? The FAQ clearly states that questions regarding “software tools commonly used by programmers” are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 4.3 the whole Xcode toolchain is bundled into a single Mac App Store application. The Mac App Store supports delta updates and the update to 4.3.1 that I’m downloading right now is ~900M, compared to ~1.5G for the whole app. So it looks like the update sizes are finally coming down, if slowly.

Answer (score 0):

I wait for a torrent these days. Not quite as frustrating as getting it 80% of the way downloaded and losing connection.

Comment: I can resume the HTTP download just fine in Safari, can’t you? But what bugs me is mainly the sheer size of the download and the amount of data I have to run through the machine to install a minor revision update.

Answer (score 0):

If you are registered apple user then u can download directly from apple site,otherwise you need to get it from torrent. like [www.thepiratebay.org](http://www.thepiratebay.org) etc