# How to update XCode when not downloaded from App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

For whatever reason I was not able to download XCode from the app store and hence had to download it from apple's developer tools. Is there any way to conveniently update XCode without having to download the whole 8 GB package everytime there is a minor update?! It's freaking me out, my Internet sucks and it usually takes like 3 hours.

Comment: (1) No, there is no other way. Long ago, there used to be programs that could self-patch with small updates, but that's a nasty security hole and is no longer viable. (2) This is in no sense a programming question. It's almost a life question. :)

Answer (score -1):

> to download the whole 8 GB package everytime there is a minor update?

Unless you absolutely have to, don't update Xcode: like a bug that's bugging you in the workflow, or macOS updates and Xcode is deprecated on the new version.

You can check the release notes to see if the update has what you need.

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes

I've been using the same Xcode version for the last one year and faced no issues. (I'm using it for C++ and very rarely python)

---

But if you need to get a newer version, App Store is still not a recommended method

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232802/cant-update-xcode
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374515/why-is-xcode-11-2-1-not-appearing-in-the-app-store-updates-tab?noredirect=1&lq=1
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252911/download-older-version-of-xcode/253269#253269

Best is to use a direct link to the file and a curl/ wget like tool which can download the file in chunks, or at least resume if disrupted.

However, this answer suggests that App Store may have smaller updates

- [Is there a better update system coming for Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449089/is-there-a-better-update-system-coming-for-xcode)

So its size vs reliability.

Comment: Unfortunately I am doing app development and whenever I get a new iOS update for my phone, I have to update XCode in order to be compatible. But thanks for your reply!

Comment: Added some more info